# jQuery delay() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show a success message upon the change of password, the issue is success message displays and vanishes in no time even though I increase the delay time.
**For testing you have to give same password and confirm password value**

Here is the code,

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2"></div>.

           <!-- This is the div where I display message -->

          <div class="col-md-8" id="alert-msg" style="display: none;">
               <div style="text-align: center;" class="alert alert-success">
                  <strong>Success! Your Request Has Been Submitted!!</strong> 
                </div>  

            </div>
        </div>    

    <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" id="pass" method="GET" action="index.php">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" name="pass1" id="f_pass">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="pass2" id="c_pass">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" id="msg-sub" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>                 
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the script part,

```
<script>
   $("#msg-sub").click(function(){
            var pass1= $("#f_pass").val();              
            if(pass1 !=='') {
                $('#alert-msg').show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);    
            }
    });         
</script>
```

Here is the [url](http://ws.rndsoftech.com/android_test/Elumalai/inventory_dicate_test/),

Please help me out, Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you can use 'vanishing thing' with fadeOut: $('#alert-msg').fadeOut(3000)

Comment: By the way using `.show()` and `.hide()` does impose a *slight* performance penalty. Not really a problem if you're only using it occasionally, but just be aware that calling it *lots* of times will slow down your page.

Comment: Have you tried a non-zero duration for.show() and .hide()? With zero duration it may not be added to the animation queue.

Comment: Clicking the button will submit the form and trigger a GET on the target page - that won't be delayed by queueing up jQuery effects. When should the notification be shown with respect to submitting the form (before? after?)

Comment: @nnnnnn I had tried with "slow" attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the `script`, you need to wrap it inside jQuery .ready method. You also need to prevent the click handler propagation by using `event.preventDefault()`

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#msg-sub").click(function(e){
     var pass1= $("#f_pass").val();              
     if(pass1 !=='') {
       $('#alert-msg').css('display', 'block').delay(3000).fadeOut(600);    
     }
     e.preventDefault();
   }); 
 });        
</script>
```

Here's a link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKLdJj

Comment: The message should fade-off in your example its just displays

Comment: I just updated the codepen with the fade effect and also a delay so the user can see the success message before it leaves.

Comment: Currently `e` is missing

Comment: @BalajiRavichandran Sure, I think it will be nice to tick right if it works, so others know its right

Comment: `e` is still missing from your answer, I think Balaji must have added it

Comment: Thanks @devnull69 Sure he did

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `submit` event is triggered since this click is on a `submit` button. Return `false` within your click handler to stop propagation. This works.

```
   $("#msg-sub").off().click(function(){
            var pass1= $("#f_pass").val();              
            if(pass1 !=='') {
                $('#alert-msg').show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);    
            }
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: or change the type of the button to `button`

Comment: @devnull69 the above code works fine, but I need to handle bootstrap form validation which will get affected on changing the button type. Is there any alternative way to achieve without changing the button